# Huawei “New tag collected, Tag is empty or phone is not aligned” message

Tags: java, android, nfc, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have an app which reads NFC tags. After reading nfc in the application on the huawei device, a new screen opens and it says "New tag collected, Tag is empty or phone is not aligned". My application switches to the background. Not like that with Samsung. Toast message pops up on Samsung and the app doesn't go to background. For this reason, my application should not go to the background on the huawei. How can i fix this?

Comment: What API are you using to read the NFC card? It's best to show your code when asking questions. My guess is `enableForegroundDispatch`, if you are using this then it is the Android standard to pause your App while the card is read and then resume it. You also need to specify which Huawei and Samsung phones and what Android version they are running and also Specify the Tag make and model, to help answer the question.

Comment: @Andrew I did not specify a model because it is like this on almost all huawei devices. yes "enableForgroundDispatch". Do you have a solution?

Comment: No solution as there is still too little to go on, may be the Tag your using in a Mifare Classic card? and may be Huawei don't support these (as not every manufacturer does).  May be you could try the better NFC Api of `enableReaderMode` as this does not pause and resume your App to read a Tag as instead a new thread is created in your app to do the reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem disappeared when the huawei beam feature was turned off